# sbt assembly missing class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt

In my SBT build files I have the following entries:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.2"
```

In my code, I use:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

val httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

val httpGet = new HttpGet(url)
```

When I run this on my machine, it works. But when I deploy the jar file (sbt assembly) to another machine I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder
```

When Unzipping the jar file, there is indeed no HttpClientBuilder class in there.

Comment: If you want to have your JARs packaged with your application, you should do a Fat JAR with `sbt-assembly`.

Comment: I was using assebly, as stated in the question's title

Answer (score 0):

How do you build jar ?

```
sbt compile
```

If you want to have fat jar you must use assembly plugin for sbt https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly and run

```
sbt assembly
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that deep in my class there was a reference to a depricated method that for some reason did not find it's way into the fat jar.

changing

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
```

to

```
httpClient.close();
```

fixed this problem.

It wasn't sbt related, but rather something to do with the java lib itself.